# composer config add repository location without the name

Tags: php, composer-php, repository, command-line-interface, config

Is there any way to use composer CLI command to add a repository location to `composer.json` but without stating its name?

You can do:

```
composer config repositories.<name> vcs /path/to/the/repository
```

But I'm interested in adding repository location without specifying its name.

Since repositories' locations can be added in `composer.json` without their names:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/igorw/monolog"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "dev-bugfix"
    }
}
```

I'm interested to add such entry:

```
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/igorw/monolog"
        }
```

by using composer CLI but command:

```
composer config repositories vcs /path/to/the/repository
```

fails.

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9918

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible at this point. If you take a look at the regex that parses your `repositories` argument (or repo/repos):

```
// handle repositories
if (preg_match('/^repos?(?:itories)?\.(.+)/', $settingKey, $matches)) {
```

https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/1.7.2/src/Composer/Command/ConfigCommand.php#L535

You see it's expecting the `repositories.name` format. My guess would be that while adding them anonymously would be fine if you don't already have repositories defined, it would break if you started trying to name some of them. Also the `unset` command wouldn't work because you haven't named it, and running the command repeatedly would continue to add them.

My guess is that it's a deliberate move not to support this. You could always open an issue on the repository to request it though.

Comment: Looking at the regex you can also use: `repoitories` ahaha TESTED

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way to do that.  I would just add it manually (without the cli tool).  I did try using `composer config repositories._ vcs /url`.  It worked, but it obviously set the name to be "_".  Then you can go in and delete that.  But if you are doing that anyway, you might as well just add it manually anyway.